# using POSIXct in R

Tags: r

I have the following code:

```
as.POSIXct(c('03/08/2015 03:08:18 AM','03/09/2014 02:01:05 AM'),
           format="%m/%d/%Y %l:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2015-03-08 03:08:18 EDT" NA
```

Why is the 2nd time returning `NA` when converted?

Comment: it works on my side: `> as.POSIXct(c('03/08/2015 03:08:18 AM','03/09/2014 02:01:05 AM'),format="%m/%d/%Y %l:%M:%S %p")
[1] "2015-03-08 03:08:18 WET" "2014-03-09 02:01:05 WET"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're working in the EDT (Eastern Daylight Time) time zone

On 09th March 2014 the clocks [went forward one hour at 02:00:00](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2014). Therefore, the time of 02:01:05 doesn't actually exist.

First you should check the source of the data; should you actually be working in EDT? 
Most likely not, so you'll want to set the `tz` argument to the actual timezone.

For example

```
as.POSIXct(
  c('03/08/2015 03:08:18 AM','03/09/2014 02:01:05 AM')
  , format="%m/%d/%Y %l:%M:%S %p"
  , tz = "EST"   ## change this to the actual timezone you need. 
  )
#"2015-03-08 03:08:18 EST" "2014-03-09 02:01:05 EST"
```